# django-admin startproject foo : Access denied

Tags: python, django, cmd

I am trying to install django and create a project I am not able to get any success I have looked on internet but could not find solution for this.
[image]

I am also running my cmd with admin. I have also check permission of folder. I also tried running in virtual env but same error.

Answer (score 0):

If you see a “permission denied” message when running django-admin.py startproject, you’ll need to change the file’s permissions. To do this, navigate to the directory where django-admin.py is installed (e.g., cd /usr/local/bin) and run the command chmod +x django-admin.py.

In Windows just run command line with Administrator privilege.

Literally [first thing in Google](https://django-book.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chapter02.html) after search: "django-admin access is denied".

Answer (score 0):

You are working in the C:\ drive,

go to another drive and create django project , most likely the problem will be solved.